# Grails form tag ID property for css

Tags: grails, gsp

When you use grails form tag  how can you have an id selector in the rendered HTML form tag?

If you use

```
<g:form action="register" controller="registration" id="registrationform"/>
```

it renders the form post URL as the `/registration/register/registrationform`.

Is there a way to provide a property that renders ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Easiest way is

```
<g:form action="register" controller="registration" name="registrationForm" />
```

The name attribute will be used to render the id attribute

You could also use the URL parameter and pass in a map for your action and controller.

```
<g:form url="[action:'register', controller:'registration']" id="registrationForm" />
```